# Sent mail: Empty headers for Outlook 2010 (corporate environment)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I've looked at [how to view source](https://superuser.com/questions/389717/how-do-i-view-source-in-outlook-2010) and [how to view headers](https://superuser.com/questions/266834/outlook-2010-view-source-of-the-mail-message). What I want are conventional (standard) email headers of yesteryear, since the source looks like HTML (or some other markup language).  For sent mail, the headers box is blank. I'm wondering if anyone else in a corporate environment sees the same thing in their sent mails?  Any idea on whether there is anything that can be done from a user standpoint to see these?

The context (not sure how much this matters) is that I want to see whether I forwarded a meeting appointment to my other account on a different network.  I don't want to do it more than once because it fills up the Inbox of the meeting organizer with notifications that the appointment has been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely normal.

Mail headers are added by the mail servers as the mail is received at each stop along the way to the recipient, so you'll never see them on the version in your email client's "sent" items.

Comment: Huh.  That makes sense.  I can't recall what was shown for the Sent mailbox in Thunderbird (which is a plain text file).  I just assumed that the headers were largely the same, but how can they be if they haven't actually been sent when a copy is put into the Sent mail box.